# Azure Data Factory falling behind schedule silently

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a number of activities running on ADF with some running every day, some hourly and one every 15 minutes.

I found the way to set up [alerts](https://datafactory.azure.com) in ADF so that failing activities will trigger an email. I have not however found the way to create more detailed custom alerts.

In this case a task that runs every 15 minutes

```
"scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
}
```

Was set to run one at a time

```
"policy": {
                "concurrency": 1
            },
```

Unfortunately the activity became locked indefinitely for a couple days. Probably on a resource lock. This caused all the time slice to stay in pending state. Waiting on concurrency. Since the initial activity slice did not fail, I got no alert and no warning.

Does anyone have an idea how to monitor failures that aren't failures in ADF like if a slice misses schedule?

Comment: This provides more information on different alerts and monitoring that can be set up for azure data factory. Check the Alert on Metrics section.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-monitor-manage-pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to turn your issues into failures.

You can add `timeout` property into pipeline execution policy:

```
"policy": {
    "concurrency": 1,
    "timeout":"00:15:00"
}
```

With this timeout your pipeline execution and related dataset slice will become `failed` after 15 minutes.

Comment: A simple clean solution. Thanks a bunch!